# Replace HTML attributes with CSS

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have many html files generated by some coworkers through Dreamweaver CS5.5 and (worse!) Frontpage 2003.  The source for these files looks horrendous and I am tasked with updating them to HTML5 format.  I found tools online for stripping out inline css and adding the code to external sheets as well as combining and merging multiple css files into a single file.

What I want to find is some system of taking the outdated html attributes such as align, valign, bgcolor, width, height, etc. and replacing them with css code.  It's way too much to do manually so I thought I could get some ideas on software to help me do this.  Thanks.

**Edit:** Henry wants to know the tools I found.  Here they are:

http://inlinecssextractor.com/home.html (Inline CSS Extractor)

http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/ (CSS Compressor)

Comment: You could try to loop the files in a read I/O and then parse it into a DOM parser (example for PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and then make the modifications, and then afterwards copy a duplicate of the file into a new folder (to safe keep the originals).

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS part, [fantasai](http://fantasai.tripod.com/qref/HTML4/deprecated.html) will help you styling in modern CSS each deprecated attribute you removed (or replaced by a class having the same styling)

Good luck with the `<ms:o` part. And `<font>` :/